# How to redirect a referal url to a signup page?

Tags: redirect, signup

I tried to create a referral url which looks something like, [example.com/?ref=123456](http://example.com/?ref=123456). So when some one clicks on that URL, it needs to redirect to the signup page, like [example.com/signup][2].

Also, needs to get the refer URL id, when signing up using this link.

I used [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), which takes 2 options,

Source URL: /?ref=(*)

Target URL: /signup

But it is not working.

Any other way to redirect to signup page and capture the referal url?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your index page.

You could add.

```
if( isset( $_GET['ref'] ) && $_GET['ref'] !== '' )
    wp_safe_redirect( '/signup' )
```

Then, on the sign up page add:

```
$the_referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

So you can do whatever you want with that, I would add some escaping etc and you'll prob have to `str_replace()` to get the ID solely.

Thanks.